# symfony2 mongodb reference query field()->in()

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I have a problem with a query from a repository class.

I need this result for mongodb

```
db.RequestsPictures.find({ 
    "picture.$id": {
        "$in":[
            ObjectId("5013a65dd1853eb02c000000"), 
            ObjectId("5013a47dd1853e4919000001")
        ] 
    }
}).sort([ ]);
```

This query works fine in **MongoDB** but I don't know how to write this query with the `QueryBuilder`.

If I test this code - doctrine will set bad quotes

```
   $ids = array(
        'ObjectId("5013a65dd1853eb02c000000")',
        'ObjectId("5013a47dd1853e4919000001")'
    );

    $ids = implode(',', $ids);
    return $this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->field('picture.$id')
        ->in(array($ids))
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute()
        ->toArray();
```

The result of this code:

```
db.RequestsPictures.find({ 
    "picture.$id": {
        "$in": [         
            "ObjectId("5013a65dd1853eb02c000000"),      
            ObjectId("5013a47dd1853e4919000001")" 
        ] 
    }
}).sort([ ]);
```

The quotes after `[` and before `]` are needless.

So can you tell me how can I disable the auto quotes in the `QueryBuilder`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution:

```
 $ids = array(
    new \MongoId('5013a65dd1853eb02c000000'),
    new \MongoId('5013a47dd1853e4919000001')
);

return $this->createQueryBuilder()
            ->field('picture.$id')
            ->in($ids)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute()
            ->toArray();
```